# sql error : only one expresssion can be specified in the select list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am getting this error ( see title). How can i correct this:

sql

```
use adventureworks
go

select si.CustomerID,
'myField' =
            CASE
                 When (Select Top 1 FirstName,LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null Then 
            Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName,LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar)
            Else ''
            END
from Sales.Individual si
where si.CustomerID=11000
```

Comment: You got the answer or not...or still confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the query

```
use adventureworks go  

select si.CustomerID, 'myField' =             
      CASE    When 
          (Select Top 1 FirstName From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null 
              Then              
          Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName
                   From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar)             
              Else ''             
     END from Sales.Individual si where si.CustomerID=11000
```

The erro is because you are choosing FirstName and LastName both so to remove erro choose one of them either firstanme or lastname or combine both in one

for example

```
Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName as fullName
                       From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.
```

this will resolve your issue

for more deatil check : [Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/error116/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select two values and treat them as one expression:

```
select top 1 FirstName, LastName ...
```

This should probably be change to something like this:

```
select top 1 FirstName + ' ' + LastName ...
```

---

A fully functioning version would be something like this:

```
select
    si.CustomerID,
    CASE
       WHEN
           (Select Top 1 FirstName + ' ' + LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null
       THEN
           (Select Top 1 FirstName + ' ' + LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  )
        Else ''
    END [myField]
from
    Sales.Individual si
where
    si.CustomerID=11000
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a subquery in your query like that, SQL can only return one field from one record. You probably wanted to concatenate those fields, which you can do like this:

```
use adventureworks
go

select si.CustomerID,
'myField' =
            CASE
                 When (Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null Then 
            Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar)
            Else ''
            END
from Sales.Individual si
where si.CustomerID=11000
```

Or you can just chose one of those fields in the subqueries.